# how to get position and length of unzipped gzipstream in c#?

Tags: c#, gzip, binaryreader

i'm trying to read .gz files using binary reader by first unzipping with gzipstream, and then creating a new binary reader with the gzipstream. however, when i try to use the BaseStream.Position and BaseStream.Length of BinaryReader (to know when i'm at the end of my file), i get a NotSupportedException, checking the doc for these fields in GZipStream Class shows:

Length
This property is not supported and always throws a NotSupportedException.(Overrides Stream.Length.)

Position
This property is not supported and always throws a NotSupportedException.(Overrides Stream.Position.)

so my question is how can i know when i'm at the end of my file when reading a decompressed GZipStream using BinaryReader? thanks

here is my code:

```
Stream stream = new MemoryStream(textAsset.bytes);
GZipStream zippedStream = new GZipStream(stream, CompressionMode.Decompress);
using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(zippedStream))
    while(reader.BaseStream.Position != reader.BaseStream.Length)
    {
        //do stuff with BinaryReader
    }
```

the above throws:
NotSupportedException: Operation is not supported. System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream.get_Position()

due to the BaseStream.Position call in the while()

Comment: I haven't actually used this, but couldn't you just keep reading until it fails?

Comment: BinaryReader is a .Net class.  A zipped file doesn't have to follow its specification. So directly use *zippedStream.Read*  until it returns <=0 (most simple way would be zippedStream.CopyTo())

Comment: @Eser checking for <=0 worked, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can copy your `zippedStream` to `MemoryStream` instance, that can be read fully using `ToArray` function. That is the easiest solution I can think of.

```
Stream stream = new MemoryStream(textAsset.bytes);
byte[] result;
using (GZipStream zippedStream = new GZipStream(stream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
{
    using (MemoryStream reader = new MemoryStream())
    {
        zippedStream.CopyTo(reader);
        result = reader.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Alternatively if you want to read stream in chunks

```
using (GZipStream zippedStream = new GZipStream(stream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];
    int read;
    while ((read = zippedStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
    {
        // do work
    }
}
```

Comment: GZipStream does not contain a definition for 'CopyTo'

Comment: @RussellButler every *stream* contains a *CopyTo* for .Net>=4.0. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.copyto(v=vs.110).aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream.copyto(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @RussellButler what exactly your compiler says and what version of .Net you use in your project?

Comment: @YaroslavVeremenko it just says "GZipStream does not contain a definition for CopyTo and no extension method CopyTo"...not sure what version of .Net, but i'm using c# in Unity 2017.1.1f1, so maybe 4.6?

https://blogs.unity3d.com/2017/07/11/introducing-unity-2017/

in any case i solved the problem using a >= 0 hack, so its no problem. thanks for your reply though :)

Comment: @RussellButler do you mean you used the second piece of code in my reply or similar?

Comment: no i did not, i did what Eser suggested in his comment to my original question.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you are decoding you can read the first type into a byte array using the BinaryReader and then use BitConverter to convert these bytes into the type you want. You can then use BinaryReader as normal until the start of the next record.

```
byte[] headermarker = new byte[4];

int count;

// if bytes available in underlying stream.
while ((count = br.Read(headermarker, 0, 4) > 0 )
{
    Int32 marker = BitConverter.ToInt32(headermarker, 0);

    //
    // now use Binary Reader for the rest of the record until we loop
    //
 
}
```